# Order by association status count in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, psql

I created a Candidate model with a has_many association with Response model

In the response model, we are also storing the status as pending and completed

I want to add the scope which orders the candidate according to the number pending status

E.g

```
Candidates1  -> repsones1 --> {status: "pending"}
             -> repsones2 --> {status: "completed"}
*******************************************************
Candidates2  -> repsones1 --> {status: "pending"}
             -> repsones2 --> {status: "pending"}
*******************************************************
Candidates3  -> repsones1 --> {status: "completed"}
             -> repsones2 --> {status: "completed"}
*******************************************************
Candidates4  -> repsones1 --> {status: "pending"}
             -> repsones2 --> {status: "pending"}
```

So the from above example, I want to order like this

```
Candidates2 #pending status count is 2
Candidates4 #pending status count is 2
Candidates1 #pending status count is 1
Candidates3 #pending status count is 0
```

I am using Postgres as a database

> I don't want to add any count attribute on the Candidate model

I tried some scope

```
class Candidate < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :responses

  scope :order_by_pending_responses, -> {
     joins(:responses)\
    .order("responses.status='pending' DESC")
  }
end
```

but getting duplicate candidates
if I added uniq keyword on scope then getting an error on pagination

Answer (score 1):

`ORDER BY` clauses in SQL can include aggregations and conditions:

```
scope :order_by_pending_responses, -> {
    left_joins(:responses)
      .group("candidates.id")
      .order("SUM(CASE WHEN responses.status = 'pending' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC")
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, but instead of count I used sum and get the correct result.

order("sum(CASE WHEN responses.status = 'pending' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC")

Comment: @Akshay Of course, you are right. I fixed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
scope :order_by_pending_responses, -> {
    left_joins(:responses)
      .where(responses: { status: :pending })
      .group("candidates.id")
      .order("count(responses.id) DESC")
}
```

However, if you are going to call this scope frequently, I suggest you to use built-on [counter_cache](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#controlling-caching):

```
class Response < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :candidate, counter_cache: true
  # ...
end

# add a migration
add_column :candidates, :responses_count, :integer, default: 0

# Candidate model
class Candidate < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :order_by_pending_responses, order('responses_count DESC')
  # ...
end
```

Comment: I don't want to use **counter_cache** and by where condition you can't get a **complete status candidate** in the list

Comment: I did not understand what do you meant by "can't get a complete status candidate in the list". Isn't that solved by left_joins?